# How to form a exact query for finding id's inside array

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I've a document like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("xxx"),
    "users" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("xxx")
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("yyy")
        }
    ]
}
```

users is an array, which can contain two or more than two objects.

If I've to request strictly two objects via a mongo query, how can I do it?

```
.find({ 
    "users._id" : { $in: [ObjectId("xxx"), ObjectId("yyy")] }
})
```

This above query will fetch all the docs that've either've xxx user or yyy user in them. How can I form a query where if the both xxx and yyy are only there, then only that doc is to be fetched.

Let me know if you need more info to understand the problem. And huge thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: try `$all` operator instead of `$in`.

Comment: yes. $all is working fine. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [$all](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/all/) to force the need for all ids in the array to match but it is not enough on it's own as you'll still match documents with those two users + other users.

To combat that you will also have to make sure the `users` array is of size 2, you can do it like so:

```
db.collection.find({
  $and: [
    {
      "users._id": {
        $all: [
          ObjectId("609a80e3c548140e5859d6de"),
          ObjectId("60136b272c1e946545da6204")
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "users.2": {
        $exists: false
      }
    }
  ]
})
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/SCPAskZe2ym)

Comment: Awesome. It's working even if we have more than two users. But can you please tell me what this "user.2" is doing. I understand that it is checking for length of 2, but can you point me out to mongo docs, so I can read more about it.

Comment: 'users.2' is the 2 index in an array, so if `users.2` exists than it means the array has at least 3 items in it.